# Spring boot Quartz, prioritize particular job execution

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have 1 application as a producer(scheduler) of jobs and N applications as an consumers (executors).
**Is there any way how to prioritize execution of particular job using Quartz?**
f.e.: at one moment i have 1000 jobs in queue and i need to execute 1 particular job with the highest priority

One possible solution could be set up different group name for the primary jobs. But is it possible to set up for 1 of my consumer apps to execute only jobs with particular group name?

Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: what is the mechanism you use to put the messages in?

Comment: `JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
 
SimpleTriggerFactoryBean triggerFactory = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);`

Comment: i just solved this by creating another scheduler which has reserved thread for itself and executes only these particular jobs